# How to get a numpy array into same byte object as with open().read()?

Tags: python, image, numpy, byte

I have originally posted this question here:
https://community.plot.ly/t/images-are-not-displayed-after-altering/26521/2
But I feel like it got more appropriate for stackoverflow.
So it basically boils down to me trying to figure out how i can get the same byte object that is created when I open a .png file with

```
    with open('temp.png', 'rb') as f:
        encoded=base64.b64encode(f.read())
```

after I already have opened the image as a numpy array.
When I just try to convert the numpy array into a bytes object it looks quite different from what I get with open:

```
(io.BytesIO(imageio.imread(img_path))).getvalue()[0:20]
Out[70]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

(imageio.imread(img_path)).tobytes()[0:20]
Out[71]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

(open(img_path, 'rb').read())[0:20]
Out[72]: b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x04\x00'
```

and also with different lengths (the conversion of the np array being a magnitude longer).
What is the difference between the methods, and how can I achieve what open.read() does after I have converted the image to a np.array?

Comment: I don't see any `numpy` array code.

Comment: why you need that?

Comment: You do realize that the two are quite different things? If you open with imread you get a raw, uncompressed pixel grid. If you open with open you  get the png encoded image which I believe is a header with metadata followed by compressed image data. To get the second from the first you'd have to reencode as png using the exact same parameters (compression level etc.) as used for the original png.

Comment: @Paul Panzer thanks for clarifying. Is there a way to convert to png format without saving the file?
I could get around this problem by saving it as .png and reopening it, but that makes the application quite slow and I can't find any options that convert to png without saving the file.

Comment: @user11696936 check the imageio module you are using. Often, functions that have a file argument accept also a file like object in its place. You are using BytesIO already. Or maybe there is even a direct option in imageio.